Negation of monotonic and strictly monotonic functions
Suppose that $\varnothing \neq X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Then the following are true:

If the function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is not monotonic, then there exist $a<b<c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)>f(b)<f(c)$ or $f(a)<f(b)>f(c)$.

If the function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is not strictly monotonic, then there exist $a<b<c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)\geq f(b)\leq f(c)$ or $f(a)\leq f(b)\geq f(c)$.


Proof of 1. If $f$ is not monotonic, then there exist $s_1<s_2$ in $X$ such that $f(s_1)<f(s_2)$ and there exist $t_1<t_2$ in $X$ such that $f(t_1)>f(t_2)$. Let $E=\{s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2\}$, $x_L=\min E$, $x_R=\max E$, and $M=\max\{f(x):x\in E\}$. We need to consider the following cases:
i. Suppose $f(x_L)=M$. Then $x_L\neq s_1$ and hence $x_L<s_1<s_2$ with $f(x_L)>f(s_1)<f(s_2)$.
ii. Suppose $f(x_R)=M$. Then $x_R\neq t_2$ and hence $t_1<t_2<x_R$ with $f(t_1)>f(t_2)<f(x_R).$
iii. Suppose $f(x_L)\neq M$ and $f(x_R)\neq M$. Hence $f(x_L)<M$ and $f(x_R)<M$. Let $M=f(x)$ for some $x\in E$ and note that $x\neq x_L$ and $x\neq x_R$. Hence $x_L<x<x_R$ and $f(x_L) <f(x)> f(x_R)$.
Question 1. I am wondering how to apply the same approach for 2? This is what I have done so far. If $f$ is not strictly monotonic, then there exists $a_1<a_2$ in $X$ such that $f(a_1)\geq f(a_2)$ and there exists $b_1<b_2$ in $X$ such that $f(b_1)\leq f(b_2)$. Let $E=\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$, $x_L=\min E$, $x_R=\max E$, and $M=\max\{f(x):x\in E\}$.
i. Suppose $f(x_L)=M$. If $x_L<b_1$, then $x_L<b_1<b_2$ and $f(x_L)\geq f(b_1)\leq f(b_2)$. But what if $x_L=b_1$?
Question 2. I tried to solve part 2 in a different way. So we need to show that $$f \ \text{is not strictly monotonic $\Rightarrow$} \exists a<b<c (f(a)\leq f(b)\geq f(c) \ \lor \ f(a)\geq f(b)\leq f(c)).$$ So the contrapositive is
$$\forall a<b<c (f(a)> f(b)> f(c) \ \lor \ f(a)< f(b)< f(c)) \Rightarrow  f \ \text{is strictly monotonic}.$$ But it is not so clear to me how to prove that contrapositive holds.

A constant function on a $2$-element set $X$ is not strictly monotonic, but there do not exist $a\lt b\lt c$ in $X$.

As noted in a comment, proposition 2 is not quite accurate; it fails if $X$ is a $2$-element subset of $\mathbb R$.
Correctly: if $f$ is not strictly monotonic, then either (i) there exist $a\lt b\lt c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)\lt f(b)\gt f(c)$, or (ii) there exist $a\lt b\lt c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)\gt f(b)\lt f(c)$, or (iii) there exist $a\lt b$ in $X$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. If $f$ is injective then $f$ is not monotonic and (i) or (ii) holds; otherwise (iii) holds.
It follows that your proposition 2 holds whenever $X$ is not a $2$-element set. Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb R$, $|X|\ne2$, and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is not strictly monotonic. If $f$ is not monotonic, we already know that there exist $a\lt b\lt c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)\lt f(b)\gt f(c)$ or $f(a)\gt f(b)\lt f(c)$, so we may assume that $f$ is monotonic. Since $f$ is monotonic but not strictly monotonic, $f$ is not injective. Since $
|X|\gt2$, there exist $a\lt b\lt c$ in $X$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ or $f(b)=f(c)$ or $f(a)=f(c)$. In every case we have $f(a)\le f(b)\ge f(c)$ or $f(a)\ge f(b)\le f(c)$ or both.
By the way, your assumption that $X\ne\varnothing$ is not needed, since $f:\varnothing\to\mathbb R$ is strictly monotonic.

Thank you for your answer! I’m a bit confused, though. You mentioned that "since $f$ is monotonic but not strictly monotonic, then $f$ is not injective," and I agree with that. Then, you added, "since $|X| > 2$, there exist $a < b < c$ in $X$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$ or $f(b) = f(c)$ or $f(a) = f(c)$." Could you explain where you used the condition $|X| > 2$ and how these three cases follow? Thank you!

If $f$ is not injective, there exist $x\lt y$ in $X$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Since $|X|\gt2$ there exists $z\in X\setminus{x,y}$. Either $z\lt x$ or $x\lt z\lt y$ or $y\lt z$. Let $a=\min(x,y,z)$, $c=\max(x,y,z)$, and ${b}={x,y,z}\setminus{a,c}$.

Thanks a lot! That makes sense to me now. Just a small correction: I believe in your last comment, you meant "there exists $x < y$ in $X$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$." Also, very nice answer! I’d like to ask a couple of questions to make sure I understand everything correctly:

Am I right in thinking that the function $f: \varnothing \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic and strictly monotonic?




Regarding Proposition 1 in my post—i.e., "If the function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is not monotonic, then there exist $a < b < c$ in $X$ such that $f(a) > f(b) < f(c)$ or $f(a) < f(b) > f(c)$." I need to assume that $|X| > 2$, because if $|X| \in {0, 1, 2}$, then $f$ is monotonic.


I believe the same restriction should be applied for Proposition 2.


Thank you in advance!


Sorry about the typo. Yes, I meant $f(x)=f(y)$. (2) You are right in thinking that $f:\varnothing\to\mathbb R$ is monotonic and strictly monotonic; that's what I said on the last line of my answer. (3) For proposition (1) you don't have to assume that $|X|\gt2$, that follows from the assumption that $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is not monotonic. Likewise for Propsition 2 you don't need to assume that $|X|\notin{0,1}$ but you have to assume that $|X|\ne2$.


Regarding Proposition 2, if we assume that $|X|\neq 2$ and if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is not strictly monotonic then $|X|\notin {0,1}$. All this implies that $|X|>2$, right? Sorry I am a bit confused with that.

Yes, that's right.

Thank you very much! My point was to add the condition $|X| \geq 3$ to the statement because it makes it look more natural.
